# MySQL How to get numeric value after special character in varchar

Tags: mysql, sql, numeric

I have following records..

```
ABC/290116/1    
ABC/290116/2    
ABC/290116/10
```

How do i get the most-right numeric value (1,2,10,..) after slash "/" from those records? 
If you have PHP code to auto reset the value monthly greatly appreciate.

Many thanks

Comment: It might be worthwhile to consider what the value means, and if the database table(s) should be normalized. At first glance it appears to be in violation of the first normal form..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you know all the records will be in the format `ABC/x/y` and there will be `/` as separators, you can use [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) to do something like:

```
$record = "ABC/290116/10";
$value = explode("/", $record);

echo $value[2];
```

Note that in this case, `explode()` will split `$record` into three parts, `ABC`, `290116` and `10`. `$value[2]` will get you the third part.

In a scenario where you will be looping through multiple records, do something like:

```
$records = array (
    "ABC/290116/1", "ABC/290116/2", "ABC/290116/10"
)

foreach($records as $record) {
    $value = explode("/", $record);
    // Do something with your $value[2].
}
```

Comment: When i try to call $record with mysql, i get "Warning: explode() expects parameter 2 to be string" error. how do i get this $record to be a string?

Comment: solved: i did 
$query=mysql_query("bla bla bla");
$record=mysql_fetch_array($query);
$value=explode("/",$record[0]);

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL, you would use `substring_index()`:

```
select substring_index(col, '/', -1)
from t;
```

If you want this as a number:

```
select substring_index(col, '/', -1) + 1
from t;
```